# Compare two groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

In an experiment, 20 project experts (10 from technical roles and 10 from non-technical roles) were instructed to estimate the effort required to complete a web development project.They could use their prefered estimation strategy. They each provided effort estimations in work-hours.

There is a hypothesis, that technical roles provide more optimistic effort estimates than experts in non-technical roles. How could that hypothesis be statistically proven with the available data?

Comment: You might want to provide more information on the data you have. How was effort measured? How many people were asked?

Comment: Please explain what you understand thus far & where you are stuck. Then we will provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on wheather the variances in your groups (technical / non-technical) can be assumed to be equal you can use **Student's t-test** or **Welch's t test** to test if the means of both groups are significantly different.

Equal Variances: Student's t-test / Unequal Variances: Welch's t test

To test if the variances can be assumed to be equal you can use **Levene's test**. Another test you could use is Bartlett's test.

Because you have a directed hypothesis (mean of technical < mean of non-technical) you have to use the [one-tailed test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-_and_two-tailed_tests).

Have a look at the wiki pages for the [Student's t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test) and [Welch's t test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t_test) for more information.

Comment: I also added information on using one-tailed test because your hypothesis has a direction.